# Persistant drive viewable files

Tags: files, live-usb

I created a persistant drive of 500mb on my 4 gig usb drive using netbootin and a linux image.   If I choose to save files (word documents, pictures) where do I see the persistant drive to save them too.  Looked in MNT folder and don't see it there.  Where can I save them so I have at next re-boot or if I use a different computer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They will reappear wherever you saved them upon reboot.

The persistent drive feature saves any changes to the file system and lays them on top of the read-only file system of the LiveCD.

Edit: Be aware, that you can't easily open your added or altered files from another system. You would first have to save them on a regular disk or USB drive. The one you're already booting Ubuntu from will do, if it has enough space.

Disclaimer: I should say, I never tried this myself, just read the docs.

Comment: Thanks again, as long as they can be opened on the USB drive that I have the OS installed on is what is important to me.  I am using SoldyXK (KDE version).  I appreciate your responses.

Comment: I tried this with Soldyxk (debian-based) and found it doesn't work.  I save a JPG and ODT file and they were not there on reboot.  Going to try it with Linux Mint next.

Comment: Still having issue.  I have successfully accomplished this with only an Ubuntu image.  I prefer not to use this, due to the Unity Environment.